# Totalling Values and Finding the Top x Values

Tags: sql

Situation:

I have a database that contains sales records, each record has a ID (PK), ProductCode, Year, Month, SalesVolume.

As a user I will specify the year, so if I specify 1980, I will query the database for all the records that correspond to that year.

I am trying to create a query that will total the months SalesVolumes for the specified year, then pick the top 5 sales volume values.

What I have gathered so far is to somehow do the above, then to choose the top 5 sales volumes values, put them in descending order, and select the top 5, but that's as far as I have got

Note in a year there will be SalesVolumes for multiple products:

```
ID,     Product Code, Year, Month, SalesVolume
23041   121           1980  1      21
23042   121           1980  2      960
23043   121           1980  3      939
23044   121           1980  4      927
23045   121           1980  5      931
23046   121           1980  6      950
23047   121           1980  7      975
23048   121           1980  8      994
23049   121           1980  9      994
23050   121           1980  10     968
23051   121           1980  11     918
23052   121           1980  12     854
23425   122           1980  1      1002
23426   122           1980  2      1032
23427   122           1980  3      1090
23428   122           1980  4      1062
23429   122           1980  5      1010
23430   122           1980  6      1103
23431   122           1980  7      1214
23432   122           1980  8      1122
23433   122           1980  9      1019
23434   122           1980  10     1181
23435   122           1980  11     1343
23436   122           1980  12     1180
```

Expected Output:

For 1980

```
Product Code, SalesVolume
121         , (total SalesVolume of the 12 months)
122         , (total SalesVolume of the 12 months)
```

Comment: Can you show the desired output based on the example above? So far it's not clear what you want to get.

Comment: For 1980

Product Code, SalesVolume
121, (total SalesVolume of the 12 months)
122, (total SalesVolume of the 12 months)

Comment: Ah that edited terrible , ill add it to my original post

Comment: Looks like the answer has already been posted =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you can do - total up the sales for each item by for a given year, rank them, and then select the top 5 ranking items.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT "Product Code",
        SUM(SalesVolume) as total,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(SalesVolume) DESC) as rnk
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Year = 1980
    GROUP BY "Product Code"
) A
WHERE rnk <= 5
```

If you want to do select the top 5 per year for all years, you can do that too:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Year,
        "Product Code",
        SUM(SalesVolume) as total,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Year ORDER BY SUM(SalesVolume) DESC) as rnk
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Year, "Product Code"
) A
WHERE rnk <= 5
```

Comment: Could you explain what the A is for after the bracket, I am not that deep into SQL yet :)

Comment: Glad I could help. The `A` is just giving a name to the subquery. I'm not sure about the reason, but it's required (at least by SQL Server). The `SELECT *` could be `SELECT A.*` and you could even join another table to `A`.

Comment: @MitchellT: Note that if e.g. two products tied at the max total and then four more products tied at the next largest total, `RANK()` would rank them as `1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3`, and all those rows would be returned by the query, based on the `rnk <= 5` condition. If you want *no more than* 5 products, use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead. If you want up to 5 different *figures* (and however many products having those totals), use `DENSE_RANK()`.